# Python ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Tags: python, split, iterable-unpacking

In my text file i have Strings data i am try to unpack them using Split() but unfortunately giving me error as "ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)"
Plz help to solve me if you know

```
with open('Documents\\emotion.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        clear_line = line.replace("\n", '').replace(",", '').replace("'", '').strip()
        print(clear_line)
        word,emotion = clear_line.split(':')
```

I have this type of data

```
victimized: cheated
accused: cheated
acquitted: singled out
adorable: loved
adored: loved
affected: attracted
afflicted: sad
aghast: fearful
agog: attracted
agonized: sad
alarmed: fearful
amused: happy
angry: angry
anguished: sad
animated: happy
annoyed: angry
anxious: attracted
apathetic: bored
```

Comment: What about empty lines (especially at the bottom where they are hard to spot). Should they be skipped or is that an error?

Comment: Yeah, you probably have empty lines at the bottom of the file. I can't reproduce the problem with just the data you gave, but can if I add empty lines.

Comment: @wjandrea, that's spot on.

Answer (score 1):

It is **happening because of more than 1 empty lines at the end of file**.
Rest of your code is working fine.

You can do below to avoid the error.

```
if not clear_line:
    continue

word, emotion = clear_line.split(':')
```

Answer (score 0):

That error can be caused if you have any empty lines in your file, because you're telling python to unpack `['']` into `word, emotion`. To fix the problem, you can add an `if` statement like this:

```
with open('Documents\\emotion.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        if line:
            clear_line = line.replace("\n", '').replace(",", '').replace("'", '').strip()
            print(clear_line)
            word,emotion = clear_line.split(':')
```

`if line:` means if the line is not empty.